# Escaping double quotes in JSON result

Tags: c#, json

I have a set of codes where i have done error handling. I want the result to be `{"ErrorMessage": Server is down}` However i keep getting the result as `{"ErrorMessage":"Server is down"}`.

**Here are my codes:**

```
catch (Exception e)
        {
            var result = "Server is down";
            return Ok(new { ErrorMessage = result });
        }
```

I have tried using '@' and '\' characters however it did not work. How do i escape those extra double quotes? Someone please do help me. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: `{"ErrorMessage": Server is down}` is invalid JSON.  See http://www.json.org/ for confirmation: *A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, **wrapped in double quotes**, using backslash escapes.*  Are you absolutely, positively sure you want that?

Comment: Please let me know the right way to do this would greatly appreciate

Comment: `{"ErrorMessage":"Server is down"}` is already the right way.  That's a valid JSON object with a single property named `ErrorMessage` whose value is the string `Server is down`.  Or by *Please let me know the right way to do this* do you mean, "Please tell me how to generate this invalid JSON anyway, I am absolutely positively sure I need it."

Comment: I thought both the ways were incorrect so i was looking for another way to do it. Now i know `{"ErrorMessage":"Server is down"}` is correct so thanks :)

Comment: However just out of curiosity, can i please know how to get this: `{"ErrorMessage": Server is down}` ? Why @ \ can be used in other cases but in this it does not work?

Comment: The double-quotes are not being added by the c# compiler, they are being added by the JSON serializer called by the `Ok()` method that takes the POCO `new { ErrorMessage = result }` and serializes it to a JSON string.  It's not clear from your question what framework and serializer you are using.  If your framework were using Json.NET and you wanted it to generate invalid JSON, you could do `return Ok(new { ErrorMessage = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JRaw(result) });`  But why would you?

Comment: Oh ok now i understand. I got confused as previously i did a project in java and the result came out as `{"result": true}` i realise that, that `true` did not have double quotes since it was coded in a way that the output result should be a boolean

Comment: For this however, the output is a string therefore it is right to have that double quotes and that is the valid JSON way. Please do correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: *For this however, the output is a string therefore it is right to have that double quotes and that is the valid JSON way.* -- yes, this is correct.  The json standard is here: http://www.json.org/ and shows that a JSON primitive value is either a quoted string, a number, `true`, `false` or `null`.

Comment: Ok thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to leave the result as it is as `{"ErrorMessage":"Server is down"}` is the correct way of displaying a JSON output. As explained by @dbc, that is a valid JSON object with a property named `ErrorMessage` whose value is the `string Server is down`.